# Signal-to-noise ratio under heteroscedasticity

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

I want to be able to compare simulated datasets with and without heteroscedasticity, in the context of a linear regression:

$y = X \beta + \epsilon$

Since I want  to make sure that when I introduce heteroscedasticity I do not induce too much noise in the regression, the SNR seems to me the best (and only) option to make this comparison. But I have found many definitions, and [only one adapted to this special case of heteroscedasticity](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fe09/efb519b26d59c64c715c4efcbe752dc933be.pdf) (page 104):

$SNR =\frac{\beta^TX'X\beta}{\sum Var(\epsilon_i)}$

The issue with this definition (apart from the fact that it seems to return values too high) - and others I have encountered, for instance [here](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2008/WCE2008_pp1063-1069.pdf) (page 2), is that they never provide a citation, as it should be obvious for the reader where it is coming from. Is there any SNR literature that develops a definition for the linear regression, and specifically for the case of heteroscedasticity?

Comment: In what way do you wish to "compare" datasets?

Comment: The work I'm doing concerns variable selection and how it can be affected by heteroscedasticity. If I introduce it in a previously homoscedastic dataset with no benchmark, variable selection's performance may decrease simply because I'm adding extra noise. Making the SNR (or some similar measure) equal between datasets would guarantee I do not have that problem.